# Using Picker from emoji-mart offline

Tags: reactjs, cdn, offline, emoji

I'm using Picker from https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart in reactjs application. Currently using emoji-mart 3.0.1 and react 16.13.1

```
<Picker
       emoji='point_up'
       i18n={emojiLang}
       onSelect={props.setEmoji}
       showSkinTones={false}
       skin={skin_yellow}
       title={'title'}
/>;
```

when `Picker` is called, it will get the spritesheets from cdn (unpkg.com), as stated in the docs:

`Sheets are served from unpkg, a global CDN that serves files published to npm.`

This works fine if user has access to internet. But since some users need to access it via intranet (no internet access), is there any workaround to this? Maybe download the sheet separately and serve it as local asset?

Thanks!

Comment: hi, perhaps cache it on the first download?

Comment: the user will not have access to internet at all. so I don't think it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the library itself (the url is in `packages/emoji-mart/src/config.js`).

Be mindful of the `emoji-mart` license.